# MySQL Dual table Join Dual table

Tags: mysql, join, dual-table

Is there a way to JOIN fields from the dummy DUAL table in MySQL?

Say I have a

```
SELECT 1 as n1 FROM DUAL

n1
--
 1
```

and a

```
SELECT 2 as n2 FROM DUAL

n2
--
 2
```

Can I join both selects with a Join in some kind of query as...

```
SELECT 1 as n1 FROM DUAL JOIN (SELECT 2 as n2 FROM DUAL) ON 1=1
```

?

Comment: What do you want the result to look like? MySQL permits you to leave out the `FROM` clause entirely, so you don't even need `FROM Dual`.

Comment: set them up as sub selects and alias the tables then join.

Comment: Depending on your intent, it may just be as simple as `SELECT 1 AS n1, 2 AS n2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
Select t1.n1, t2.n2 
from (select 1 as n1) t1 
CROSS JOIN (Select 2 as n2) t2;
```

Here's another

```
Select t1.n1, t2.n2 
from (select 1 as n1, 'A' as ID) t1 
INNER JOIN (Select 2 as n2, 'A' as ID) t2
  on T1.Id = T2.ID;
```

and you could just do

```
Select 1 as n1, 2 as n2
```

but I assume there's a reason you need the joins.